# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Android 8.0 outside Code on SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

**The problem**

Since the upgrade to Android 8.0 I get many crash reports stating an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` that occurs outside my code.

**The crash report**

There is no code in the [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) app responsible for the crash and it seems to be a bug in Android itself.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1314)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:680)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:672)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText (AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2474)
  at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal (TextView.java:10357)
  at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:7307)
  at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal (View.java:7266)
  at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:7251)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource (AccessibilityRecord.java:146)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource (AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
  at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal (View.java:7203)
  at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal (TextView.java:10338)
  at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (View.java:7191)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal (View.java:7053)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (View.java:7038)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal (View.java:7015)
  at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEventInternal (TextView.java:10725)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent (View.java:6982)
  at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged (TextView.java:9269)
  at android.widget.TextView.spanChange (TextView.java:9505)
  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanRemoved (TextView.java:11943)
  at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.sendSpanRemoved (SpannableStringInternal.java:408)
  at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.removeSpan (SpannableStringInternal.java:243)
  at android.text.SpannableString.removeSpan (SpannableString.java:50)
  at android.text.Selection.removeSelection (Selection.java:109)
  at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTakeFocus (LinkMovementMethod.java:239)
  at android.widget.Editor.onFocusChanged (Editor.java:1163)
  at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged (TextView.java:9586)
  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal (View.java:6593)
  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch (View.java:10823)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:10802)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3160)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants (ViewGroup.java:3204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus (ViewGroup.java:3163)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:10769)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:10711)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable (ViewRootImpl.java:3430)
  at android.view.View.setFlags (View.java:13277)
  at android.view.View.setVisibility (View.java:9378)
  at android.app.Activity.makeVisible (Activity.java:5412)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3785)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2898)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1593)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6541)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Possible cause**

Since it happens on a `TextView` I think it has to do with these elements I use:

```
         <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txtAlso"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#0000AA"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:textIsSelectable="true"
              android:text="" />
```

**Tried solution**

To hopefully fix this bug I have rewritten the `TextViews` to the code below, removing the `isSelectable` tag and preventing the view to focus.
Since I cannot reproduce the bug myself I hope to get more information soon. If anyone has information, insight or knows the solution reply or comment.

```
         <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txtAlso"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#0000AA"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
              android:text="" />
```

Comment: Why downvoted? Please comment at least when you down vote.

Comment: People see known types of exceptions - immediately assume that's a duplicate 

Comment: Great, well I wish it was, have searched hours and did not find the same problem, did find some similar issues in earlier android versions but nothing about Android 8. Thanks for the comment @azizbekian

Comment: Did you find any problem? I'm having same issue, but cannot reproduce it.

Comment: The tried solution seems to work so far. So add `android:focusable="false"` to the textviews that cause it.

Comment: @BasvanStein did you find a fix? It appears to us that it only happens to Honor phones.

Comment: @Jonas it still occurs, but less frequent. Not sure on which phones it occurs, have seen logs with samsung phone and a few others.

Comment: @BasvanStein thanks for the update!

Comment: Adding android:focusable="false" to textview is the solution for problem @Bas van Stein

Comment: I also found out this error is triggered with `LOWER` and `UPPER` in tinysql on some devices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same crash in my app. After alot of research and testing I manage to recreate it. The crash happend only on Oreo Android 8.0 devices and almost only on Samsung devices.

The IndexOutOfBounds exception was in my case triggered when clicking on a link created by Linkify.

```
Linkify.addLinks(text, path, null, matchFilter, transforFilter);
```

I removed Linkify and found another way to do what I needed without Linkify.

Comment: I did not use linkify, but I found out that there is a bug in the tinysql implementation of toUpper() and toLower() on Samsung Android 8. In my case removing those finally solved thr problem. I will mark your answer as accepted since this is indeed another Samsung issue that causes this crash.

Comment: Adding tv.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO); before linkify, fixed it for me.