# Android Crash Log from an Xamarin Mobile App

Tags: android, xamarin

I have some androids phones that have recently started crashing.  Is there a way to help narrow down this crash information I retrieved from the Google Play Console?
Thanks for any direction!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrEjz.png)

Comment: use an error log / crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms or raygun.io

Comment: Thanks Jason.   We are going to be using AppCenter.   Is there other ways since we have not implemented yet?

Comment: @HenryEgal Hi, the crash logs is full? From the shared image, can not find where problem is. It needs detialed logs to check.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT yes that is the full log from what Google Play Console has.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the devices/users, a [device crash report](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report) would help to troubleshoot the issue further:

```
$ adb bugreport E:\Reports\MyBugReports
```

From the stack trace you provided, it looks similar to the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421454/indexoutofboundsexception-in-android-8-0-outside-code-on-spannablestringbuilder), caused by a third-party library. In your case, it can be either your code or any third-party library which can cause the crash. I would recommend trying to identify which code created `Spannable` in your app and isolate/remove/replace it.

Comment: Great thanks!  I am working on making sure everything is the most recent version.   I will search for Spannable and see if I can isolate.  Thanks for the assistance and I will report back on my findings.